# setState called in render prop is causing a react warning

Tags: reactjs

I have the following component that takes a render prop that it passes values to a child component.  [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/usemachine-typescript-problems-nvcr0) is a codesandbox that shows the problem.  Press submit and look at the console.

Here is the component:

```
export const FormContainer = function FormContainer<V>({
  initialValues,
  validate,
  render,
  ...rest
}: FormContainerProps<V>) {
  const [hasValidationError, setHasValidationError] = useState(false);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!hasValidationError) {
      return;
    }

    scrollToValidationError();

    () => setHasValidationError(false);
  }, [hasValidationError]);

  return (
    <>
      <Formik
      >
        {({
          isSubmitting,
          submitCount,
          isValid,
          errors,
          values,
        }: FormikProps<V>) => {
          const invalid = !isValid;
          const submitted = submitCount > 0;

          if (submitCount > 0 && invalid) {
            setHasValidationError(true);
          }

          return (
            <>
              <Form>
                  <div className={styles.form}>
                    {render({
                      values,
                      errors,
                      isSubmitting,
                      invalid,
                      submitCount,
                    })}
                  </div>
              </Form>
            </>
          );
        }}
      </Formik>
    </>
  );
};
```

If there is a validation error then `setHasValidationError` is called which causes this error from react

```
Warning: Cannot update a component (`FormContainer`) while rendering a different component (`Formik`). To locate the bad setState() call inside `Formik`, follow the stack trace as described in 
    in Formik (created by FormContainer)
    in FormContainer (created by Home)
    in Home (created by Context.Consumer)
    in Route (created by App)
    in Switch (created by App)
    in Router (created by App)
    in App
```

I'm not saying this warning is wrong.  Calling `setHasValidationError` does not seem ideal here but the call to `scrollToValidationError();` that will get called in the initial `useEffect` hook is async and it needs to go outside the render function.

What can I do?

Comment: I think hackape has it right, eff an eslint anyway right ?   :P

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In order to avoid this issue with Formik, you can wrap your state calls in setTimeouts, this should do the deal:

```
        setTimeout(() => setHasValidationError(true), 0);
```

This is also what Formik does in their official documentation. It's a problem they have had for a while, the trick is to make the state update run on the next cycle tick.

Also see: https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/issues/1218

Comment: I think `useEffect` instead of `setTimeout` is even better, so you can avoid the unfortunate case when `setState` is called after the component got unmounted. I did a safety check into the [source code](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/blob/26c4f8627a5ecfd81ec2196c7a9687b3f39f2836/packages/formik/src/Formik.tsx#L1024), it looks fine, though eslint naively complained.

Answer (score 2):

I think Ali's answer using `setTimeout` is legit. I'd like to add that `useEffect` is IMO better solution. For it further prevent the unlikely but still possible error case when `setHasValidationError` is called after the component got unmounted.

(eslint naively complains `useEffect` is unsafe to use here but I checked with [source code](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/blob/26c4f8627a5ecfd81ec2196c7a9687b3f39f2836/packages/formik/src/Formik.tsx#L1024) it's totally fine.)

```
// here I rename useEffect to mute eslint error
const nextTick = useEffect;

<Formik>
  {({
    isSubmitting,
    submitCount,
    isValid,
    errors,
    values
  }: FormikProps<V>) => {
    const invalid = !isValid;

    nextTick(() => {
      if (submitCount > 0 && invalid) {
        setHasValidationError(true);
      }
    }, [submitCount, invalid]);

    // ...
  }
</Formik>
```

Comment: Reminder: The [React docs suggest](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level) we call `useEffect` in the same order every time in a component. This means `useEffect` should come before any conditional returns, not run in loops, and not run in callbacks. The Formik example is using the `useEffect` in the callback for `<Formik>`. For this reason, the `setTimeout()` approach makes the most sense.

Comment: You're right. I did take that into consideration, thus I checked the source code. For current implementation it's fine. But yeah, no guarantee that Formik will keep consistent internal implementation so your reasoning holds.