# invoke function from context in Formik component will cause warning

Tags: reactjs, formik, react-context

```
   <Formik
        enableReinitialize
        initialValues={testState}
        validateOnChange
        onSubmit={onSubmit}>
            {(formProps) => {
              formProps.dirty && !isEmpty(formProps.touched) && handleFormDirty();
              return (
                <TestComponent />
              );
            }}
     </Formik>
```

handleFormDirty is a function from React context, which will change the state in React context. However, when I try to invoke handleFormDirty, it will show warnings like:

**To locate the bad setState() call inside `Formik`, follow the stack trace as described**

I found a similar question here [setState called in render prop is causing a react warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61031464/setstate-called-in-render-prop-is-causing-a-react-warning)  but it seems like the answer is not perfect.

Any ideas? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why are you calling it on every render? What does it actually do?

Comment: I need to pop a modal when I click cancel button or breadcrumb link to leave the page when the form gets dirty and touched. Then I use handleFormDirty to change state isFormdirty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it in an effect. You can't update state at the same time as render:

```
const ParentComponent = (props) => {

   return (
     <Formik
        enableReinitialize
        initialValues={testState}
        validateOnChange
        onSubmit={onSubmit}
     >
          {(formProps) => <MyFormComponent {...formProps} handleDirty={handleFormDirty}/>}
     </Formik>
   );
}


const MyFormComponent = ({handleDirty,...formProps}) => {

  useEffect(() => {
    formProps.dirty && !isEmpty(formProps.touched) && handleFormDirty();
  },[formProps.touched,formProps.dirty,handleDirty]);

  return (
    <TestComponent/>
  );


}
```